# What is the meaning of the edge `pos` attribute in DOT files?

Tags: graph, matplotlib, graphviz, networkx, pygraphviz

I am trying to layout some graphs and I'm using `pygraphviz` for it.  I build my graph, and execute

```
graph.layout(prog='dot')
```

When I perform `print graph`, it spits out the DOT-format representation, which looks like this:

```
...
94   [height="0.5", pos="1485,18", width="0.75"];
93 -> 94     [pos="e,1485,36.104 1485,71.697 1485,63.983 1485,54.712 1485,46.112"];
98   [height="0.5", pos="1557,18", width="0.75"];
97 -> 98     [pos="e,1557,36.104 1557,71.697 1557,63.983 1557,54.712 1557,46.112"];
...
```

For each node, it's pretty clear what the `pos` attribute means.  But what does it mean for the edges?  I believe it might somehow refer to a cubic spline representation, but how would I use these points if I wanted to manually draw the edge in matplotlib?

Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 0):

This file:

```
# edge.dot

digraph G {

  A [label = "A"  xlabel="a" pos="0,100" ]
  B [label = "B"  xlabel="b" pos="100,0"]

  A -> B  [label = "A->B www"  xlabel="a->b"]   
 [pos="0,100 0,0 0,0 100,0"]
  

}
```

draws a curved edge when run with neato:

```
dot -Kneato -n2 -Tpng -O ./edge.dot
```

EDIT: the e is for end, and s is for start for arrow head positions.
The following points define a Bezier curve ( or if not technically a Bezier curve something very similar.)

```
pos="s,15.188,84.812 e,84.997,15.003 22.335,77.665 38.894,61.106 61.363,38.637 77.873,22.127"
```

[https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node12.html#:~:text=A%20B%C3%A9zier%20curve%20is%20a,the%20shape%20of%20the%20curve](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node12.html#:%7E:text=A%20B%C3%A9zier%20curve%20is%20a,the%20shape%20of%20the%20curve).

Answer (score -4):

Answer is here:
http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:splineType

Comment: Please explain how you used those points to "manually draw the edge."