# GraphViz DOT output: What are the 4-6 "pos" coordinates for an "edge"

Tags: graphviz

I just started to experiment with GraphViz's "neato" command for
Kamada-Kawai graph visualization (solved using stress majorization).
I am particularly interested in extracting the laid out node
coordinates for external processing.

I was looking at [this
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11765555/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-edge-pos-attribute-in-dot-files)
to figure out the "pos" attribute for graph edges in the output DOT
file.  The attribute consists of 4 coordinate points.  One helpful
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69490693/2153235) says that the
series of coordinats (not necessarily 4) are the control points of a
spline, likely a [Bezier
spline](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node12.html#:%7E:text=A%20B%C3%A9zier%20curve%20is%20a,the%20shape%20of%20the%20curve).
The answerer is "compound eye", who I'll refer to as "CE".  Here is
the example given:

```
// digrfG.dot
//-----------
digraph G {

   A [label = "A"  xlabel="a" pos="0,100" ]
   B [label = "B"  xlabel="b" pos="100,0"]

   A -> B  [label = "A->B www"  xlabel="a->b"]
   [pos="0,100 0,0 0,0 100,0"]

}
```

In Bash, it is processed by GraphViz using:

```
# Make image:
#------------
dot -Kneato -n2 -Tpng digrfG.dot >| digrfG.png

# Make output DOT file:
#----------------------
dot -Kneato -n2       digrfG.dot >| digrfG_out.dot
```

The output is:

```
# digrfG_out.dot
#---------------
digraph G {
   graph [bb="-7,0,154,151"];
   node [label="\N"];
   A [height=0.5, label=A, pos="27,118",
      width=0.75, xlabel=a, xlp="-3.5,143.5"];
   B [height=0.5, label=B, pos="127,18",
      width=0.75, xlabel=b, xlp="96,43.5"];
   A -> B [label="A->B www", lp="42.5,75.5",
           pos="27,118 27,18 27,18 127,18",
           xlabel="a->b", xlp="63.5,60.5"];
}
```

My edge coordinates do not match
[CE's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69490693/2153235), neither in the
numerical quantities nor in the number of coordinates.  While I have 4
coordinates, CE has 6, including 2 coordinates at the start of the
series prefixed by "s," and "e,".  The [Bezier curve
page](https://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node12.html#:%7E:text=A%20B%C3%A9zier%20curve%20is%20a,the%20shape%20of%20the%20curve)
cited by CE gives the impression that typical Bezier splines have 4
control points, *including* start and end points, though the math
allows for more.  [This Micrsoft
page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-bezier-splines-about)
reinforces this impression of a 4-point default.

[This GraphViz
page](http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/splineType) shows that
an edge's "pos" attribute contains a spline, starting with start and
end points, prefixed with "s," and "e," as per CE's output, but the
syntax is puzzling.  If it is regular expression syntax, then there
are 4 or more coordinates following *optional* start and end points.
That might explain why I have no coordinates prefixed with "s," or
"e,", but I have 4 coordinates.

In `digrfG_out.dot` above, if I compare the 4 coordinates with the
node coordinates, it is clear that the first and last of the 4
coordinates match the node coordinates.  **It seems that CE's GraphViz
defaults to 6 control points and explicitly designates start and end
points at the head of the list of coordinates, whereas my GraphViz
defaults to 4, without special treatment of the start and end
points.** Since [GraphViz's spline
page](http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/splineType) is so
ambiguous, I was wondering if this interpretation can be confirmed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest skipping CE's explanation (not necessarily wrong, but maybe ambiguous) and go to the sources on the Graphviz website.
Yes, Bezier curves require 4 points per "segment" (my term) but the last point in a segment is also used as the first in the next segment.  Graphviz's arrowheads use separate points - for one end of the arrowhead.

The optional **s** (start) and **e** (end) points are for optional arrowheads.  Then 4 required points and then optional sets of 3 points.
See p.36 https://www.graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf, https://forum.graphviz.org/t/how-to-control-the-points-of-splines/1087, and https://forum.graphviz.org/t/fun-with-edges/888 - in addition to the (*yes, regular expression*) http://www.graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/splineType/
I hope this helps.

Any edge can have arrowheads, even in a non-directed graph.  **Digraph** just sets the default (arrowhead or no arrowhead).  The **dir** attribute (https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/dir/) explicitly sets arrowheads.
Finally, arrowhead shape (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/arrows.html) can be "none".

```
graph {
  A--B [dir=forward]
  C--D [dir=back]
  E--F [dir=both]
  G--H [dir=none]
}
```

**Dot** produces this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, sroush.  Would you be able to elaborate on what you mean by optional arrow heads?  I've only tried a digraph and a graph, and it seems to me that the decision between those options determines whether edges are directed.

Comment: Thanks for the update, sroush.  It was very helpful.  I found that my directed graph has 5 coordinates, the first prefixed with "e,".  This makes sense, since the arrow head is at the end of the arc.  I suspect that the coordinates marked "e," are for the tail of the arrow head.